# Is it possible to check if a button is clicked in a different page in Java?

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I want to check if a button is clicked in the previous activity in Java. If 1st button is clicked, then it will proceed to 2nd page following function 'a'. If 2nd button is clicked, then it will proceed to 2nd page, following function 'b' and so on.

Basically, there will only be 2 main activities, 1st page and 2nd page. If any button is clicked in the first page it will go to the second page, but each button will execute different lines of codes(or functions) in the second page. Is it possible or what is the code for this?

Comment: Yes, it is very easily possible. One easy way to manage this is via a global boolean value that you toggle/change when the button is pressed, then you simply check that boolean value in your other stage `if(isButtonOnePressed == true){//Do Something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

#### First page:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,YoursecondactivityName.class).putExtra("click",1)));
btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,YoursecondactivityName.class).putExtra("click",2)));
btn3.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,YoursecondactivityName.class).putExtra("click",3)));
btn4.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,YoursecondactivityName.class).putExtra("click",4)));
btn5.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,YoursecondactivityName.class).putExtra("click",5)));
```

#### Second page:

Now you have to get that what was clicked. In the on create add this:

```
switch(getIntent().getIntExtra("click",1)){
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 1 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 2 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 3 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 4 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 5:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 5 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Here from the first activity you pass which button was clicked using intent. Now in the second activity, you get it and then write the code which you want.

If you want my entire activity code, it is below

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.b1),btn2 = findViewById(R.id.b2),btn3 = findViewById(R.id.b3),btn4 = findViewById(R.id.b4),btn5 = findViewById(R.id.b5);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("click",1)));
        btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("click",2)));
        btn3.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("click",3)));
        btn4.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("click",4)));
        btn5.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("click",5)));
    }
}
```

And now my second activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        switch(getIntent().getIntExtra("click",1)){
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 1 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 2 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 3 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 4 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 5:
                Toast.makeText(this,"button 5 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. May I know what the "firstClick" and true false button is for in the first page? I am implementing this for 5 buttons so do I have to rename some of the buttons to "secondClick" and so on?

Comment: ok then you can pass a string to the next activity. get the string and verify it. That way it can work. If you need help with what i am saying, i will post the code.

Comment: I think I need help with the code haha

Comment: ok wait. I will update my answer

Comment: I tried it but an error occurs when I run the app. On the code `btn1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  startActivity(new Intent(this,YoursecondactivityName.class).putExtra("click",1));
})` the error is `lambda$onCreate$0$` . There is also another error `ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)` on the first page. I apologize for having too many questions, I am doing this for a project and I am still learning

Comment: Does the error come when you compile or when you run?

Comment: ok. I have edited the answer. Please check –

Comment: I tried it again but the error is still the same. The error comes when I run the app and click the button on the first page. There is also an error that I think I overlooked yesterday which is, `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` I really appreciate the help.

Comment: It has already worked but the codes under the switches are not working, but I guess it is my fault haha. Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: Oh I think there is still something wrong with it. When I click the the buttons from 1st page, it does proceed to the second activity but it does not follow the codes I have written in the second page (the codes I have written inside the switch)

Comment: ok. let me check

Comment: I have edited my answer. please check. I have also added the activity code

Comment: Good day, I am writing here again because I needed help with this code. It already works but I want the text view I have written inside the case to change when a button on the second page is clicked, which also depends on the button that was clicked previously.  If you have the time to teach, I would like to give an example of it so I can explain it properly

Comment: Thank you very much! Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466739/is-it-possible-to-put-a-button-function-inside-switch-intent